# Concurrent.futures works well in command line, not when compiled with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have a python script which takes custom command line arguments and calls **concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor**

This calls multiprocessing.resource_tracker which has the following code

```
cmd = 'from multiprocessing.resource_tracker import main;main(%d)'
r, w = os.pipe()
try:
    fds_to_pass.append(r)
    # process will out live us, so no need to wait on pid
    exe = spawn.get_executable()
    args = [exe] + util._args_from_interpreter_flags()
    args += ['-c', cmd % r]
```

works well in command line

Now when compiled with pyinstaller, when this code gets executed, the file where I am taking input arguments is getting called and I getting the following error

**Argument Parsing Error - invalid choice: 'from multiprocessing.resource_tracker import main;main(11)'**

I have used freeze_support but no use. How to avoid this error? Is there any way in which we can accept those arguments?

Python Version: 3.8, Pyinstaller version: 3.6 OS: Darwin

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that `spawn.get_executable()` is your "compiled" program when started from PyInstaller, where it is pointing on the installed python version otherwise.

The argument parsing of your program refuses the complex arguments that you're passing.

You should distribute your program without pyinstaller, but with a (portable) python installation like Anaconda.

The alternative would be to add an option in your parser to accept a `-c` switch which takes an argument.

When this switch is passed, just call `exec` on what is passed to simulate `-c` python switch.

Comment: The code I have included in the question is from mutliprocessing package itself .Since the concurrent and multiprocessing packages are default python packages, is it advisable to edit the library code? Any idea on the alternatives for ProcessPoolExecutor?

Comment: no you should not edit library code, my bad. Is pyinstaller an absolute requirement by your end?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: If i somehow accept all the command line arguments, will my script automatically run with the arguments provided by multiprocessing since we are packaging the python with the script using pyinstaller?